# How i can change the name of chapter from Chinese into English?

Tags: xetex

I am working on my thesis, and for this, I am using `ctexrep.cls` package. But i am facing a problem that my chapter number is present in Chinese, but it should be in English.

[image]

Comment: What you probably need is ```report.cls``` ?

Comment: `\documentclass[scheme=plain]{ctexrep}` or `\documentclass{report} \usepackage{ctex}`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. \documentclass[scheme=plain]{ctexrep} Solve the problem for me.

Comment: Using the package {ctexrep}, I want that my chapter number and title of chapter come in the same line.  For example  Chapter 1 Introduction

Comment: That's another question.

Comment: Can you answer me this question?. I did changes as you suggested but now facing the problem in which chapter title is on different line, but i want that both title and chapter should be in same line.