# I am using "ctexrep.cls" package. But I am facing a problem that my chapter title and chapter number present in different line

Tags: xetex, ctex

I am using "ctexrep.cls" package. But i am facing a problem that my chapter title and chapter number are present in a different lines. The question I ask before in which someone suggests me to use [schem=plain] so my chapter will change from Chinese into English. Its works for me but now the second problem which I am facing is that the chapter number and title are in different lines but I want it in the [image]same line. Below I provide the link of my previous question. I also uploaded the picture of my problem which I need to solve.
[How i can change the name of chapter from Chinese into English?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/635896/how-i-can-change-the-name-of-chapter-from-chinese-into-english#635896)

Comment: Under `scheme=plain`, you need to issue `\ctexset{chapter/aftername=\quad}` in the preamble to change the styling of chapters. The default for `scheme=plain` is `\par\nobreak\vskip 20pt`, which starts the chapter title on the next line. This is documented in Table 12 on page 21 of the `ctex` documentation.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Its work for me.